# Cacheable periodic recycle-able been creation with Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I am developing a **Micronaut API that depends on another networked service**.

Because the connection to the remote networked service consumes resources in the remote service I am considering making the bean responsible for establishing the network connection recycle-able.

The idea would be allow the remote server to also recycle resources and because the remote network service may be down this would allow the API to be able to recover in this instances.

Is there any recommend pattern to do this in Micronaut ?

Many thank, kindly
  Oscar

Answer (score 0):

> ...I am considering making the bean responsible for establishing the
>   network connection recycle-able.

Micronaut provides a really simple and powerful mechanism for helping with that.  See the docs on declarative http clients: https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.1/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation.

In short, you write a client like this...

```
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.*;

@Client('https://someplace.com') 
public interface PetClient { 

    @Post('/pets/{name}/{age}')
    Pet save(String name, int age); 
}
```

An instance of that interface will added as a bean that you can inject into any other bean...

```
@Controller("/somepath")
public class SomeController {

    public SomeController(PetClient petClient) {
        this.petClient = petClient;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Jeff , in my case this is not one HTTP service but one connection to a Corda DLT that it is backed up one ActiveMQ/Artemis and I have one bean that wraps this connection, it is one instance of  net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps

Comment: The way I would address that is quite different than the way I would addressed what was is in the original question above.